# Grunt Livereload on a localhost started with WAMP/XAMPP/UniServerZ

Tags: gruntjs, localhost, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to take my front-end workflow a step higher with Grunt tasks.

I have set up a couple of tasks in my Gruntfile.js. For now there are only grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-contrib-watch so that .css files are automatically recompiled whenever I make a change to my .sass files.

**What I want to achieve is the following:**

I want to add a task that would listen to my local server that was started with UniServerZ/XAMPP/WAMP or any other provider. I want to trigger a reload each time I edit any file in the server base directory.

I know that it is quite easy to set up such a task with, e.g. 'grunt-express' which starts a local server for you, but I really want to listen to a server started with UniServerZ/XAMPP/WAMP.

I will be grateful to see example configuration for such scenario if it is possible to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did it with Wamp 2.2 on Windows 7.

First, you need [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) properly setup with livereload. I also use [grunt-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass) and not [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass), because grunt-sass use [Libsass](http://libsass.org/). LibSass is a C/C++ port of the Sass engine, and it is faster.

To install them, use these commands :

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
npm install grunt-sass --save-dev
```

Here is an example of Gruntfile :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: 'folder/to/your/sass/**/*.sass',
                tasks: ['sass:dist'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
            //Watch your theme files
            livereload: {
                files: ['pathToTheme/*.php', 'pathToTheme/img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                },
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: ['where/to/find/additional/@import/scss/files'],
                outputStyle: 'nested',
                imagePath: 'how/to/rewrite/image/path',
                sourceMap: true
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'output/file.css': 'input/file.scss'
                }
            }
        },
    });

    // Default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

    // Load NpmTask
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

};
```

You could save yourself some time with [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks), and remove the manual loading of task :

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks
```

Then I use the [livereload plugin for firefox (or chrome or safari)](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions-).

Start the grunt watch task, open your site on localhost, and click on the icon in your browser.  Now if you edit a watched file, the page should update accordingly.

[A solution exist](http://robandlauren.com/2014/02/05/live-reload-grunt-wordpress/) to add the livereload js in your Wordpress automatically (in function.php):

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1'))) {
    wp_register_script('livereload', 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1', null, false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('livereload');
}
```

Comment: Dont you need to do any configuration changes in your grunt task for it to know where to refresh the page?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add an example Gruntfile. I hope it will help.